# Google Translator, How to prevent restoring original language

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

Here is the code am using for google translator for my website.
When click reload the page then it will reset the original text, how to prevent this.

```
 <script>
     function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement(
         {
           pageLanguage: 'en',
           includedLanguages: 'ar,en',
         },
      'google_translate_element',
    );
   }
   </script>
   <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"> 
   </script>
```

Comment: What does `reset the original text` mean?

Comment: @GirkovArpa here is my goal is when select language Arabic from the drop down it should translate the whole website page to the Arabic language. I have chosen only 2 languages in my drop down select language.  If I choose Arabic language and when I go to next page it will reset to the original text(english). Please can you suggest.thanks in advance

Comment: you can save language id in cookies